# How to get a data from JSON in React Native?

Tags: json, react-native

When I run the below code in my react-native project

```
console.log("Response= "+JSON.stringify(response));
```

I can get output like below in my console.

```
Response= {"assets":[{"height":3888,"uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.facebook2/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_6b8db334-4fcc-40ba-94a0-325191a89011.jpg","width":5184,"fileName":"rn_image_picker_lib_temp_6b8db334-4fcc-40ba-94a0-325191a89011.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","fileSize":1914937}]}
```

How I print the 'uri' from that JSON response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data we can break it down by what we see. So, with JSON we have a Javascript Object which contains a param of assets. So to print assets we would `console.log(response.assets)`

Assets is an array with one item, so we want to get the first item from that which would be `console.log(response.assets[0])`.

Then we want the uri from that first assets object which would be `console.log(response.assets[0].uri)`

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation) to access the properties of an object.

In your `response` json, it is seen that it has an array with name `assets`. The required property `uri` is inside the array. You can access it simply by

```js
response.assets[0].uri
```

if there were multiple items in your assets array, you can simply loop over the array and get the values,

```
const length = response.assets.length;

for(let i=0; i< length; i++)
  console.log('URI is = ', response.assets[i].uri)
```

```js
const response = {"assets":[{"height":3888,"uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.facebook2/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_6b8db334-4fcc-40ba-94a0-325191a89011.jpg","width":5184,"fileName":"rn_image_picker_lib_temp_6b8db334-4fcc-40ba-94a0-325191a89011.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","fileSize":1914937}]};


console.log('URI =', response.assets[0].uri)
```

Comment: Thank you I got it :)